# AngularJS not show values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155809/angularjs-not-working) article but still have question because I am new in AngularJS. I create Web Application and add AngularJS Core through Nuget Manager.

I try the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>First Page</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
   {{2+2}}
</body>
</html>
```

So, here I expect my web page shows 4 but it still shows expression.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your script is loading for angular.js.

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>First Page</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
   {{2+2}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dear thanks with angular.min.js its work fine. It means instead of angular.js use angular.min.js, only one question if I need to use all three i.e. angular-mocks.js, angular.js and angular.min.js what is the sequence of adding.